# Generate region description for `RegionPlot`

Tags: plotting

in the past I did something like

```
RegionPlot[x > 0 && x < 0.001`, {x, -0.001`, 0.002`}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> LightGray]
```

But I want to automate this to more gray stripes. For example if I define

```
{0,0.001,0.003,0.006}
```

I want to have gray stripes between 0 and 0.001 and another strip between 0.003 and 0.006 and so on If I extend the set.
How can I do this?

Comment: Something is wrong in your statement...

Comment: Sorry. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = ((x > #[[1]] && x < #[[2]]) & /@ {{0,0.001}, {0.003, 0.006},
 {0.007, 0.01}});
 RegionPlot[\[ScriptCapitalR], {x, -0.001, 0.02}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!